# Localisation platforms and translation services

Tags: localization, translation, gettext, saas

I am currently conducting some research on externalised translation services, and how to integrate them into our development workflow.

I have come across various services, and find it difficult to compare them:

- transifex
- crowdin
- localizejs
- tran.sl
- oneskyapp
- smartling

We are managing a large content website, using 2 methods:

- gettext for the "static" text
- different versions of the content (1 for each language) managed through a CMS.

The difficulty for us is to commission translations manually, it just doesn't well. We would like to automate the process instead.

1. whenever the gettext files are updated, content is sent automatically to a translation service.
2. whenever the content is updated, it is also pushed to a translation service.

It seems that all services above are designed to meet those requirements. So the question is which criteria to use to compare those various services?

Comment: www.sitetran.com please add to the list.

Answer (score 0):

The answer has a couple of different aspects.

Firstly, it will depend on the specific CMS you are using and how much you want to change your system. Namely, some of those services have to incorporate your website into their system or incorporate quite a few things into your system to achieve that degree of full automation. So you'll have to check with each one, I guess (although I have no direct experience of these services).

Otherwise, you might be advised to consult with a localisation agency and choose a localisation plug-in for your CMS and settle for a degree less automation. The process has to detect the changes, export the modified pages/contents as an XML or XLIFF file and send it to the translation service, it also has to recognise receipt of the translated file and re-import it. How much of that will happen without a supportive, prompting click or two from you, I'm not sure.

(The gettext PO files can usually be provided direct to a translator or agency who import them into their translation memory system and recognise changes since the last time they had them, only translating the changed segments. Here it pays off to work with the same translator or agency over time.)

Secondly, it depends on how many languages? All of the above gets potentially more complicated when it is being translated into more than one language.

Thirdly, who is translating? The services that offer real 'crowdservicing' often end up in a scenario where very short pieces of text without context are delivered to whichever translator happens to be awake and online at that moment. My recommendation would be specialised localisation agencies working with the relevant CMS plug-ins who should be able to offer higher quality by giving your contents to the same translator every time, or one of a small team, who then get a chance to develop a feel for your contents and translate accordingly.

Hope that helps,